# sorting problem - fill containers

Tags: python

The setup look like:

```
leaf: "weight_1", "weight_2"

container: "max_weight_1", "max_weight_2", "on_call"
```

Every container can hold multiple leafs, but each maximum weight (summarized) can not be crossed.
"on_call" is the number of available containers.

My goal is to evenly distribute the leaves to high containers available so they fill up equally.

note:

- few containers as possible
- containers should be well filled
- only one type of container (weight specifications) can be used
- each container type has own weight specifications
- each leaf has individual weights

It should work in python, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be framed as [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). In Python, there is a [bin packing package](https://pypi.org/project/binpacking/).

Comment: thx, that's an interesting package, but not usable in my case with different weights.